# Playing multiple audio files in an order Xcode 4.3

Tags: file, audio, xcode4.3, playback

Hey all I'm trying to play multiple audio files in a certain order and when I run my code it plays all of them at once. I know where the problem is I just can't figure out how to separate each file. I'm using xcode 4.3

```
[callSignPlayer play];
[VFRPlayer play];
[airportPlayer play];
[weRAPlayer play];
[aircraftPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found was creating a loop that moved to the next audio file... as seen here

```
for (int soundsIn=0; soundsIn < totalSoundsInQueue;) {

    NSString *sound = [theSoundArray objectAtIndex:soundsIn];
    while(![Player isPlaying]){

       Player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:sound ofType:@"caf"]] error:nil];


        [Player setVolume:1.0f];
        [Player play];
        //Increment for loop counter & move onto next iteration
        soundsIn++;
}
```